# Comments in Edits?

Tags: discussion

I came across a suggested edit for this answer: [Fujifilm X-T20 vs Pentax K-3 II. Am I missing any significant differences?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100835/fujifilm-x-t20-vs-pentax-k-3-ii-am-i-missing-any-significant-differences/100839#100839)

[image]

[image]

I rejected the edit as an attempt to reply. Is this a correct SOP for this type of edit? The edit was made by a user that does not have the reputation needed to comment.

Comment: I just want to know where all of these "cheaper non-IS lenses" are? Third party lens makers that make lenses in different mounts, some with IBIS systems and some with lens based systems, tend to price lenses for both systems the same. If one compares native lenses from an IBIS system to native lenses for a system that uses IS, and AF capability, focal length, maximum aperture, aberration correction, and image quality are taken into account, the lenses for the IBIS systems are usually just as much, if not more, than the lenses with IS!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct to reject edits that place contradictory comments within an answer.

In general, if one feels the content of an answer is incorrect, it should be placed in a comment. If one feels extremely strongly about it, the opposing view should probably be presented in another answer (not as a comment to the existing answer, but rather as another self-contained answer with a different position on what the correct answer is).

Comment: Is there a way to allow new users the ability to comment by vote? Or move the edit to a comment by vote / admin? I agree with your thought, just curious.

Comment: @Hueco the best way is just to up vote some of their answers.  It doesn't take much to be able to comment.  Moderators can convert answers to comments, but it really isn't ideal for them to post an answer just so a moderator can convert it to a comment, they should just get the 50 rep needed to comment.  It's also worth pointing out once they have enough rep on any one site, they automatically get 100 rep on any new site to jump over the initial limitations.